# Taking the limit of an implicitly defined function

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

The original excercise was to solve the
$$\frac{y'(x)}{x}+2y(x)y'(x) \log(x)+\frac{y^2(x)}{x}-\frac{y(x)}{x^2}+1=0$$
Differential equation with $y(0)=0$.
The general solution is
$$\frac{y(x)}{x}+y^2(x) \log(x) + x =C$$
This is not defined in the $x=0$ point, but $C$ might be defined to met the $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} y(x)=0$ condition. So i took the limit of both sides as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$. $x \to 0$, $y^2 \log(x) \to 0$, but the limit of $\frac{y}{x}$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ is path-dependent, so there is not any $C$ that could satisfy it. But I realized that $y$ is a function of $x$, so $y$ "can't go in every way" to the $0$; so the $C$ might exist.

Is there a way to prove if there is a $C$ which can satisfy the limit, without transforming the equation into an explicit form?

Comment: What is $f$ in the condition?

Comment: @Gribouillis I've messed it up, it supposed to be $y(x)$.

Comment: I don't see the point in not solving explicitly the quadratic equation. I obtain that either $y\sim C x$ when $x \to 0$ and $C\not = 0$ or $y \to +\infty$ depending on the root that we choose. When $C=0$ I get $y\sim - x^2$.

Comment: @Gribouillis It's a bit ugly in explicit form, and also there is 2 root for the function. It would be a bit ugly limit.

Answer (score 2):

As Gribouillis  commented, solving the quadratic in $y$ gives
$$y_1=-\frac{1+\sqrt{4 c x^2 \log (x)-4 x^3 \log (x)+1}}{2 x \log (x)}$$
$$y_2=-\frac{1-\sqrt{4 c x^2 \log (x)-4 x^3 \log (x)+1}}{2 x \log (x)}$$ Developing as Taylor series around $x=0$ gives
$$y_1=-\frac{1}{x \log (x)}-c x+x^2+O\left(x^3\right)$$
$$y_2=c x-x^2+O\left(x^3\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, but I am not looking for this type of solution - I'd like to know if it's doable (and the way of doing it if it is) in the implicit form.

Comment: Based on wolfram alpha ( http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(y%27(x))%2Fx+%2B+(2+y(x))+y%27(x)+log(x)+%2B+y(x)%5E2%2Fx+-+(y(x))%2Fx%5E2+%2B+1+%3D+0 ), the solutions have different limit from left and right:  $y_1$'s limit ( http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x+to+0,+-(sqrt(1%2Fx%5E2)+sqrt(c_1+x%5E2+log(x)+-+2+x%5E3+log(x)+%2B+1%2F2))%2F(sqrt(2)+log(x))+-+1%2F(2+x+log(x)) ) and $y_2$'s limit ( http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x+to+0,++(sqrt(1%2Fx%5E2)+sqrt(c_1+x%5E2+log(x)+-+2+x%5E3+log(x)+%2B+1%2F2))%2F(sqrt(2)+log(x))+-+1%2F(2+x+log(x)) ). Do you know it's reason?

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestion in the comment of Gribouillis, multiply the integrated equation through with $4x^2\ln(x)$ to get
$$2(x\ln(x)y(x))+(2x\ln(x)y(x))^2 = 4(C-x)x^2\ln(x)$$
or
$$
(2x\ln(x)y(x)+1)^2=1+4(C-x)x^2\ln(x)
$$
leading to the solution with $y(x)\approx 0$ for $x\approx 0$ 
$$
2x\ln(x)y(x)=\sqrt{1+4(C-x)x^2\ln(x)}-1=\frac{4(C-x)x^2\ln(x)}{1+\sqrt{1+4(C-x)x^2\ln(x)-4x^3\ln x}}
\\
\implies y(x)=\frac{2x(C-x)}{1+\sqrt{1+4(C-x)x^2\ln(x)}}
$$

---

Ignoring how to find explicit solutions per quadratic equations, you can try to insert $y(x)=Cx+Dx^2+o(x^2)$ into the original ODE,
$$
\frac{xy'-y}{x^2}+2yy'\ln x+\frac{y^2}x+1=0
\\
0=[D+o(1)]+[2C^2x\ln x+o(x)]+[C^2x+o(x)]+1=D+1+o(1)
$$
which implies $D=-1$ and provides no restriction on $C$. From the explicit solution we see that the next term is $\sim x^3\ln x$ so that higher order terms can not be computed using a simple power series approach.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not looking for this type of solution - I'd like to know if it's doable (and the way of doing it if it is) in the implicit form.

Comment: It seemls that we are not lucky with the quadratic equation.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici To be honest, I'm capable of solving a quadratic equation with parameters. The limit of it might be a harder task - I didn't try it, so I don't know if for sure if I could solve it - but I'd like to know if there is an elegant way of doing it with the implicit equation.

Comment: @Botond. Be sure that I was not kidding you in any manner ! If you think I was, I really apologize. I do not see (this is a way of speaking since I am almost blind) another way. I hope and wish better and more elgant solutions.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I didn't take it as an offense at all. It's just my curiosity (and a bit laziness) that would like to see a different solution. But after the comments and answers, I start to query the existence of the solution I would like to see. So I will solve it the explicit way, and I will use your answers.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can obtain developments without solving the equation by examining the order of magnitude of the different terms. Suppose we have
$$\frac{y}{x} + y^{1+\alpha}\log(x) + x = c$$
for some $\alpha>0$, so that we cannot solve explicitly the equation. We can write this as
$$y = cx - x^2 - y^{1+\alpha} x\log(x)$$
Suppose that we know that $y$ is bounded when $x\to 0$. We see from this equation that $y\to 0$ because all the terms on the rhs tend to $0$. As a consequence we get $y^{1+\alpha} = o(y)$, hence
$$y = O(x) + o(y)\quad \Longrightarrow y = O(x)$$
As a consequence, $y^{1+\alpha} x \log(x) = O(x^{2+\alpha}\log(x)) = o(x^2)$. Hence
$$y = c x - x^2 + o(x^2)$$
One can get more terms by writing $y = c x - x^2 + x^2 z$. It leads to
$$y = c x - x^2 - c^{1+\alpha} x^{2+ \alpha} \log(x) + o(x^{2+\alpha}\log(x))$$

Comment: Is there a difference between the big O and the small o?

Comment: Yes there is. Broadly speaking, $f=o(g)$ means that $\frac{f}{g}\to 0$ while $f=O(g)$ means that $\frac{f}{g}$ is bounded. See for example the wikipedia page about [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).